Centripetal Force Question A Level Physics. Confused on the direction each force is acting

I was watching this video and the teacher says that the Reaction force on the scale is equal to the weight - centripetal force.
However I'm confused because if the CF acts towards the centre of the Earth, like the Weight, then shouldn't we add them instead? or is the CF just the resultant between the weight and reacton force? and if that is the case then the direction towards the centre of the earth was chosen?

The first thing you need to do is to choose your system which in this case is a person.
The person has two real external forces acting on them.
The inward force of gravitational attraction due to the Earth, $mg$, and the outward force due to the scales, $R$, and $R$ is the reading on the scales.
You now have to decide on the frame of reference.
If you choose an inertial frame of reference, ie looking the the system from afar then the net force on the person $mg-R$ inwards produces a centripetal acceleration $a$ and so the equation of motion is $mg-R = ma$, just as you have written.
My advice is that you do not call $mg-R$ the centripetal force but rather you say that the net force $mg-R$ causes a centripetal acceleration.
I would also shy away from the use of the word reaction for the normal force acting on the person caused by the balance so as to avoid any confusion when it comes to a consideration of Newton's third law.

I prefer to not think of centripetal/centrifugal effects as a "force" but rather an adjustment due to acceleration.    Nonetheless, it's possible to obtain the correct answer if you want to consider it as a force.  But the fictitious force is not pointing towards the earth center, it is pointing outwards.
The scale is measuring the contact force between the person and the earth.  If the earth spun faster and faster, would the person feel slightly "pushed" harder into the earth or slightly "lifted" off the ground?  The answer is that they would feel somehow lifted, analogous to an object sliding off a turntable when the table spins too fast.  This means that the scale will read a smaller number (if they were completely thrown off, their weight could not longer offset the centripetal force and the scale would read zero).

your viewpoint has helped me understand it thanks! does that mean i can consider the centripetal as a resultant 'adujstment due to acceleration'/'force'?

The centripetal force is a genuine force and should definetely be thought of as such. It's not an "adjustment due to acceleration". It causes the acceleration.

Sometimes that is true but I don't think of it that way for this case.   If you have a mass on a string spinning about a center point, then yes.  The string provides the centripetal force to keep the mass in circular motion.  But the question was asked about a mass sitting on a spinning earth but NOT glued to it.

Agree or disagree, my way of thinking is as follows.  You don't know the reaction force F from the scale.   You know the force on the body due to gravity.  You know the acceleration of the body in the earth frame.  Put the forces on the force side of the equation and the accelerations on the acceleration side of the equation in a consistent reference frame and solve for F.   There are other ways to get the correct answer, but this one is unambiguous and, I think, leads to less confusion.

The key flaw in your thinking is that gravity IS providing the centripetal force, i.e. the force that is pulling you toward the center of your circular path.  There isn't some additional centripetal force acting on you.
The fact that gravity provides more than enough force to pull you in your circular path, means that there is still some normal force (now less than the force of gravity on you) that keeps you from falling through the floor.
The difference between the force of gravity and the normal force is the centripetal force required to make your motion circular.

thank you, why is the normal force less than the force of gravity?

If a person is moving in a circle, his velocity is changing. This means he is accelerating. The acceleration is given by $v^2/r$, directed toward the center of the circle. This is given the name centripetal acceleration.
This means the force on the person is given by $mv^2/r$, directed inward. This is given the name centripetal force. The centripetal force is the total force. Otherwise, the trajectory would not follow a circle of radius $r$ at velocity $v$.
So what are the forces acting on the person? We will assume the person is at the equator so centripetal force is directed toward the center of the earth.
Weight is the force of gravity pulling the person toward the center of the earth. At the equator, gravity is about $1000$ times stronger than centripetal force. After all, it takes $24$ hours to complete a circle.
Gravity would pull the person through the floor, except that the floor exerts an upward reaction force just strong enough to prevent that. Note that the upward force is not exactly as strong as gravity. It is a little weaker because the person is accelerating a little downward.
So we have $\vec R + m\vec g = \vec F$
Since $\vec R$ and $\vec g$ are in opposite directions, you have to subtract their magnitudes to get the magnitude of $\vec F$.
$-R + mg = F$

thank you! can you expand on why the upward force is weaker? i don't really understand what is meant by the person accelerating a little downward

The person is traveling in a circle. That means there is a centripetal acceleration toward the center. That means the total force is the centripetal force toward the center. That means the upward and downward forces do not cancel. The upward force must be weaker to leave a downward total.
